# C++ Create a dynamic array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, memory, dynamic

so I'm making a little snowboarding game. I have a class for obstacles called Obstacle. Now i'm creating a Biome class so I can randomly generate some (2D) terrain. Here is the definition of the Biome class:

```
class Biome
{ 
private:
    Obstacle * obstsInBiome;
public:
    Biome(Obstacle obsts[], int amountOfObsts);
    ~Biome();
    void draw(); // Draw the biome
};
```

Then here's the constructor

```
Biome::Biome(Obstacle obsts[], int amountOfObsts)
{
    obstsInBiome = new Obstacle [amountOfObsts]; // Creating array to hold the possible         obstacles in this biome
    for (int x = 0; x < amountOfObsts; x++) // Filling the obstacle array with the     obstacles passed in
    {
        obstsInBiome[x] = obsts[x];
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to allocate the memory to the array `obstsInBiome = new Obstacle [amountOfObsts];` I get the error: "no matching function for call to Obstacle::Obstacle()"

Is it not possible to dynamically allocate memory for objects? Can someone suggest a way to store the possible objects in each biome?

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Since you have (presumably) defined a constructor for `class Obstacle`, the compiler doesn't automatically define the default constructor (with no parameters). You need to do this yourself.

Comment: Hint: Try to default construct an `Obstacle`. You will see it has nothing to do with dynamic allocation. Try `Obstacle o;` and see.

Comment: In general the design misses [rule-of-three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Ahhhh thanks guys for your very quick and correct responses! I'm glad it was such a simple solution, I appreciate your help! Everything works great now! 
Edit: And also, thanks for that link g-makulik, looks like it'll be a good and helpful read!